# Why deploying a spring boot (Java) application to Googles App Engine gives error for both Flexible and Standard environment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

It is a Spring boot Java application using Maven.
I am using Intelij for developement.

I am availing $300 as I got by default from GCP and using it.

For a flexible environment, the app.yaml configuration is

```
runtime: java
env: flex
```

Error as below: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/dqnews/regions/asia-south1/operations/c9221a49-6939-4778-88a8-01f73f444cce error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-11-23T13:30:57.284Z11582.fw.0: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

When I using a Standard enviorment

```
runtime: java
env: standard
```

The Error showing as below

```
Java 6 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy Java 6 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for Java 6 deployment by visiting
```

Here is the links for Quotas:[free quotes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas)

It would be great to get help in detail.

1. If I need to increase my quotes, how and which component to be increased ?
2. What will be the app.yaml configuration for standard/flexible, if I have mentioned wrong?
3. Why Java 6 Error is coming ?

Comment: Why do you think the quotas are relevant? The error says nothing about quotas, it's saying you can't deploy a Java 6 app. Have a look at e.g. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAE there are two possible Java versions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java

In your app.yaml you can set:

```
service: demo
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1
```

And then in your app.yaml path:

```
gcloud init
gcloud components install app-engine-java
```